# How to get user's current internet IP address from the client side in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I want to get IP address of the user who visit my website. But I can't fetch the IP address. I'm try with the following code-

```
this.http.get('https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('res ', res);
});
```

If run the code I got the following error-

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token J in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "JSONP_CALLBACK({"ip":"49.37.11.219"});"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK"
```

name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK"
    **proto**: HttpResponseBase